# Ruby on Rails, rendering a partial using jquery is just displaying the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the following jQuery to render a partial when a button is clicked

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".service-type").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#details').html("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => 'my_partial',
        :locals => { f: f })) %>");
  });
});
```

but instead of it displaying the partial it inserts the following into my page

```
<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => "my_partial", :locals => { f: f })) %>
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: You need to process that file with ERB, it looks like you're probably serving it out of the asset pipeline instead. If you give us more information on where that code is and what its file is named, we could offer more help.

Comment: Also, just `render 'my_partial', f: f`. You haven't needed the `:partial/:locals` since Rails 2.3.

Comment: the file is named _my_partial.html.erb

Comment: Not the partial, the file that contains that JavaScript.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry. The JS is in assets/javascripts/tasks.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The JS is in assets/javascripts/tasks.js

You need to move your javascript into whichever file defines your form. You can make your file evaluate the embedded Ruby by adding a `.erb` extension, but that isn't going to help, as the form builder (`f`) doesn't exist in the context of this request.

You should move that blob of JavaScript directly into your view, probably inside your `form_for` block, so that it has access to the variable `f`, assuming `f` is a `FormBuilder`.